# SQL Server can't store more then 4000 characters in a local string variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I tried to use text or ntext as the variable's type but they are disallowed.
Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: 2000. Sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anything not MSSQL 2005 or MSSQL 2008:

---

You can get 8000 in a `varchar(8000)`

Another option is to use a temporary table and populate that with the information you need.  Use an autoindex to maintain order.

Comment: I tried to create a temporary table but it doesn't really work, any suggestions? I can't concat text fields for some reason

Answer (score 3):

TEXT and NTEXT are being deprecated in a future version of SQL Server.

Instead, you should be looking to use VARCHAR(MAX) and NVARCHAR(MAX) which remove the previous 8000 and 4000 size limits respectively, taking you up to 2^31-1 bytes.

Comment: While it's true VARCHAR(MAX) and NVARCHAR(MAX) should be used, this is not an option in SQL Server 2000.